# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, wsgi

Коллеги, добрый день.
Написал скрипт на python. Оттестировал.
Пытаюсь запустить скрипт как сервис в убунту, получают ошибку:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Загвоздка:
В первой строке скрипта явно указан адрес интерпретатора:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я просто пытаюсь запустить из консоли:
/home/sysadmin/pg_dashboard/run.py
все отрабатывает корректно.

Сам скрипт простейший, просто запускает экземпляр wsgi сервера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам то не убунтовод, но как такое возможно? если библиотека точно установлена и адрес интерпретатора точно указан (так как из консоли все четко запускается)

И в догонку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сама служба. Как видно - все элементарно.

Comment: Вы Python 3.7 сами устанавливали рядом с тем, который установлен в Ubuntu по умолчанию? Возможно такое, что вы установили meinheld для дефолтного Python, а не для вашего, который 3.7?

Comment: Да, питон устанавливал сам. Но, обратите внимание, в скрипте явно указан мой установленный питон: #!/usr/local/bin/python3.7. (И туда же установлен meinheld  )  все прекрасно запускается, если запускать не в качестве сервиса

Comment: Если думаете, что дело в строке `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7` попробуйте как-то по-другому запустить. Что, если попробовать так `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /home/sysadmin/pg_dashboard/run.py` (проверьте не опечатался ли я)?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса